# Multipart Linear Algebra Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Hi I need a bit of help on this Linear Algebra problem that was on past test in my LA course.

Let $T$ be a operator on the space $\Bbb R^3$ defined with:

$T((x,y,z)) = (x + 2y - z, y + x, -x +2y + 4z)$.

a) Show that $T$ is a linear operator on the space $\Bbb R^3$;

b) Find the matrix of the operator $T$ in relation to the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^3$;

c) Determine the basis and dimension the space $N(T)$ and $R(T)$ (also known as $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ respectively);

d) Find the matrix of the operator $T$ in relation to the basis $\beta= \{(1,0,1),(-1,2,1),(2,1,1)\}$.

As far as a) goes I know that a linear operator is a linear transformation that maps the vector space $V$ onto itself. So basically I have to show that for any vector in $\Bbb R^3$ I plug into the linear transformation I get an vector in $\Bbb R^3$, right?

For b) I would approach this as by plugging in every vector in the canonical or standard basis of $\Bbb R^3$ into the transformation. Would the matrix with these vectors as columns be the transformation matrix?

c) I know the definitions of the kernel and the image but how do I compute the basis I cannot seem to understand? Is there an algorithm for this? As for the dimension I know the dimension theorem namely that the dimension of the kernel + dimension of the image = dimension of the domain, right?

d) This I don't know how to approach.

Comment: For (a) T is linear if T(u+av) = Tu+aTv for any vectors u and v and scalar a. Parts (b) to (d) are also standard questions in any linear algebra course and you must have worked examples of such in your notes.

Comment: That's part of my problem, I don't. We just have a theory heavy course meaning we follow the teacher's book that consists of definitions, proofs and theorems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$ be defined as $T(x,y,z) = (x+2y-z,x+y,-x+2y+4z)$

a) We wish to prove that $T$ is in fact a linear operator.

`As far as a) goes I know that a linear operator is a linear transformation that maps the vector space V onto itself. So basically I have to show that for any vector in R3 I plug into the linear transformation I get an vector in R3, right?`

This is not entirely correct.  We already know that $T$ applied to an element of $\Bbb R^3$ will give another element of $\Bbb R^3$ by the definition of $T$.  Further, we do not care if $T$ is onto (the word *onto* here carries significance beyond the word *to*).  We already know that $T$ is an operator from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^3$, so all that remains is to show that it is *linear*.

That is to say, we wish to prove the following properties:

- $T(0)=0$ *for whatever concept of zero exists for the respective spaces*
- $T(\alpha v) = \alpha T(v)$ *for scalar $\alpha$ and vector $v$*
- $T(u+v) = T(u)+T(v)$ *for two vectors $u$ and $v$*

These can be summarized into one property if so desired which may save time/effort

- $T(\alpha u + \beta v) = \alpha T(u) + \beta T(v)$

So, we check:

- $T(0,0,0) = (0+20-0,0+0,-0+20+40) = (0,0,0)$, so the first property holds
- $T(\alpha(x,y,z)) = T(\alpha x, \alpha y, \alpha z) = (\alpha x + 2\alpha y - \alpha z, \alpha x + \alpha y, -\alpha x + 2\alpha y + 4\alpha z) \\= \alpha(x+2y-z,x+y,-x+2y+4z) = \alpha T(x,y,z)$, so the second property holds true
- $T((x,y,z)+(a,b,c)) = T(x+a,y+b,z+c) \\= (x+a+2y+2b-z-c,x+a+y+b,-x-a+2y+2b+4z+4c) \\= (x+2y-z,x+y,-x+2y+4z) + (a+2b-c,a+b,-a+2b+4c) \\= T(x,y,z)+T(a,b,c)$ so the third property holds true as well.

Thus we have shown that $T$ is in fact a *linear* operator.

---

b) We try to express the operator $T$ as a matrix with respect to the canonical basis.  As a side note, by skipping part (a) and completing part (b), the very *existence* of such a matrix directly implies that $T$ is linear.

We note that $T(x,y,z) = (x+2y-z,x+y,-x+2y+4z) = x(1,1,-1)+y(2,1,2) + z(-1,0,4)$ implying that the matrix representation of $T$ is given as:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-1\\1&1&0\\-1&2&4\end{bmatrix}$

Check that multiplication by a vector in $\Bbb R^3$ achieves the desired result:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-1\\1&1&0\\-1&2&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x+2y-z\\x+y\\-x+2y+4z\end{bmatrix}$

---

c) computing a basis for the kernel and range of a transformation is commonly done using row reduction.  I would expect you to have access to information on how to do Gaussian-jordan row reduction already, so I will skip over some of the details.

$rref\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-1\\1&1&0\\-1&2&4\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

The columns of the row reduced form of the matrix which have pivots correspond to which columns of the original matrix form a maximal linearly independent set.  In this case all three of the columns of the original matrix form an independent set.  Said vectors then act as a basis for the range of $T$.

Interpreting the row reduced form of the matrix as an augmented matrix with an additional column of zeroes on the far right, we interpret this as a system of equations: $\begin{cases} 1x+0y+0z = 0\\ 0x + 1y + 0z = 0\\ 0x + 0y+1z = 0\end{cases}$.  In this case, the only solution is when $x=y=z=0$, and so the nullspace (kernel) of the matrix consists only of the trivial solution:  $\ker(T) = \{(0,0,0)\}$.

The dimension of each space is the number of vectors in a basis for the space.  In this case, $dim(Im(T)) = 3$ and $dim(ker(T))=0$

---

d) For this, I find it easiest to explain using a "change of basis matrix" but you could approach the problem directly.

Abusing notation, let the matrix representation of $T$ also be simply called $T$.  $T$ will take inputs with respect to the standard basis and will output answers with respect to the standard basis as well.  We wish to modify it so that it takes inputs with respect to this other basis and output with respect to that other basis instead.

To do so, let us construct a pair of matrices which will convert from this other basis to the standard basis and back.

Let us refer to the basis $\{(1,0,1),(-1,2,1),(2,1,1)\}$ as $\mathcal{B}$ and the standard basis as $\mathcal{E}$

Consider the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1&2\\0&2&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and ask yourself what effect does it have.  (this matrix was formed by interpreting the vectors as columns and stacking the columns next to one another)

$\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1&2\\0&2&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, similarly $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ gets mapped to $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}$, so this matrix appears to convert *from* the unusual basis *to* the standard basis.

I will refer then to this as $S_{\mathcal{E}\leftarrow\mathcal{B}}$ (as operators should be read from right to left, this notation should imply that $S$ converts inputs from $\mathcal{B}$ to outputs in $\mathcal{E}$)

What then might the reverse operation be?  How do we convert from $\mathcal{E}$ to $\mathcal{B}$?  I.e. what is $S_{\mathcal{B}\leftarrow \mathcal{E}}$?  You should expect it, and indeed it is, the inverse of the other matrix (as they are inverse operations of one another).

We have then:  $S_{\mathcal{B}\leftarrow\mathcal{E}}TS_{\mathcal{E}\leftarrow\mathcal{B}}$ takes inputs with respect to $\mathcal{B}$, converts them to $\mathcal{E}$, applies the transformation $T$ to them, and then converts back to $\mathcal{B}$.

The matrix to describe such an operation can be written as:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1&2\\0&2&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-1\\1&1&0\\-1&2&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1&2\\0&2&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ and can be simplified as desired by completing the necessary matrix arithmetic.

Comment: That was amazing, concise and gave me numerous "a-ha!" moments. Thank you so much for taking your time explaining this so thoroughly!

Comment: I have one question though. When you say at d)  "so this matrix appears to convert from the unusual basis to the standard basis" when you multiplied the matrix by a vector of the standard basis (1, 0, 0) and got a vector from the unusual basis - that is (1, 0, 1). Shouldn't it be the other way around then? If the matrix multiplies a vector from the standard basis and outputs a vector from the unsual basis isn't it converting from the standard to the unusual basis?

Comment: @IreneAdler $b_1 = 1e_1 + 1e_3$.  Remember that vectors written in the form of column matrices are shorthand for linear combinations of basis elements.  So, $S(1b_1+0b_2+0b_3) = 1e_1+0e_2+1e_3$, or equivalently worded $S\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right] = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1\\0\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.  It takes input in terms of the basis $\mathcal{B}$, and rewords them in terms of the standard basis.